# Effectively removing rows from a Pandas DataFrame with groupby and temporal conditions?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with tens of millions of rows:

```
| userId | pageId | bannerId | timestap            |
|--------+--------+----------+---------------------|
| A      | P1     | B1       | 2020-10-10 01:00:00 |
| A      | P1     | B1       | 2020-10-10 01:00:10 |
| B      | P1     | B1       | 2020-10-10 01:00:00 |
| B      | P2     | B2       | 2020-10-10 02:00:00 |
```

What I'd like to do is remove all rows where for the same `userId, pageId, bannerId`, timestamp is within `n` minutes of the previous occurrence of that same `userId, pageId, bannerId` pair.

What I'm doing now:

```
# Get all instances of `userId, pageId, bannerId` that repeats,
# although, not all of them will have repeated within the `n` minute
# threshold I'm interested in.
groups = in df.groupby(['userId', 'pageId', 'bannerId']).userId.count()

# Iterate through each group, and manually check if the repetition was
# within `n` minutes. Keep track of all IDs to be removed.
to_remove = []
for user_id, page_id, banner_id in groups.index:
   sub = df.loc[
      (df.userId == user_id) &
      (df.pageId == pageId) &
      (df.bannerId == bannerId)
   ].sort_values('timestamp')

   # Now that each occurrence is listed chronologically,
   # check time diff.
   sub = sub.loc[
     ((sub.timestamp.shift(1) - sub.timestamp) / pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)).abs() <= n
   ]

   if sub.shape[0] > 0:
      to_remove += sub.index.tolist()
```

This does work as I'd like. Only issue is that with the large amount of data I have, it takes hours to complete.

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['userId','pageId','bannerId'])['timestamp'].diff()`

Comment: Thank you very much. Such a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

To get a more instructive result, I took a bit longer
source DataFrame:

```
  userId pageId bannerId            timestap
0      A     P1       B1 2020-10-10 01:00:00
1      A     P1       B1 2020-10-10 01:04:10
2      A     P1       B1 2020-10-10 01:05:00
3      A     P1       B1 2020-10-10 01:08:20
4      A     P1       B1 2020-10-10 01:09:30
5      A     P1       B1 2020-10-10 01:11:00
6      B     P1       B1 2020-10-10 01:00:00
7      B     P2       B2 2020-10-10 02:00:00
```

Note: *timestap* column is of *datetime* type.

Start from defining a "filtering" function for a group
of *timestap* values (for some combination of *userId*,
*pageId* and *bannerId*):

```
def myFilter(grp, nMin):
    prevTs = np.nan
    grp = grp.sort_values()
    res = []
    for ts in grp:
        if pd.isna(prevTs) or (ts - prevTs) / pd.Timedelta(1, 'm') >= nMin:
            prevTs = ts
            res.append(ts)
    return res
```

Then set the time threshold (the number of minutes):

```
nMin = 5
```

And the last thing is to generate the result:

```
result = df.groupby(['userId', 'pageId', 'bannerId'])\
    .timestap.apply(myFilter, nMin).explode().reset_index()
```

For my data sample, the result is:

```
  userId pageId bannerId            timestap
0      A     P1       B1 2020-10-10 01:00:00
1      A     P1       B1 2020-10-10 01:05:00
2      A     P1       B1 2020-10-10 01:11:00
3      B     P1       B1 2020-10-10 01:00:00
4      B     P2       B2 2020-10-10 02:00:00
```

Note that "ordinary" *diff* is not enough, because eg. starting from the
row with timestamp *01:05:00*, two following rows (*01:08:20* and *01:09:30*)
should be dropped, as they are within 5 minutes limit from *01:05:00*.

So it is not enough to look at the previous row only.
Starting from some row you should "mark for drop" all following rows until
you find a row with the timestamp more or at least equally distant from the
"start row" than the limit.
And in this case just this rows becomes the starting row for analysis of
following rows (within the current group).

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much. I believe I have it working using `by_time = df.sort_values('timestamp').groupby(['userId', 'pageId', 'bannerId']).timestamp.diff() / pd.Timedelta(minutes=1) ; by_time.loc[by_time < nMin]`. I tested it with a few use cases, so it seems to be doing the job.